# setting jstree pane to be apple theme not working

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using jstree plugin as below and it works as a default view:

```
$("#div1").jstree({
    "xml_data": {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "data.xml"
        },
        "xsl": "nest"
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "xml_data", "ui", "types"]
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
    $("#div1").jstree("set_theme", "apple");
```

When I use this `($("#div1").jstree("set_theme", "apple");)`, all the folder images and dots go away. I really like the apple view and wish to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

style.css file missing in my apple folder. Once I put the file there, I am golden.